# "cannot resolve findviewbyid in fragment" error

Tags: java, android, fragment, findviewbyid

I'm trying to move Floating Action Button into my Fragment. But I'm getting an error about findViewById. It's "**Cannot resolve method 'findViewById**'

I researched, i found so many things but i'm not good at this. Can anyone explain me how can i solve this error? I tried "Invalidate Caches/Restart" and "Clean and Rebuild Project", but it didn't work.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Floating Action Button
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // intent
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you making floating action button in the main activity or in the fragment?

Comment: Floating Action Button was on my MainActivity. But I'm trying to move on my Fragment. Fragment is in MainActivity. I want two FAB for two fragments

Comment: you should make the fab button at the fragment instead at the main activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findviewById()` do not belongs to `Fragment` class, but `Activity`.

You said you're inside a `Fragment` and want to access some view in the `Activity`, you must use `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab)`.